# How to implement offline google maps in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my Android app I have used the google maps in which I used to show some locations with markers in the map.
But even when there is no Internet connection also I want to show these locations in the maps.
Generally when there is no data connections google maps wont be loaded right, how can I show locations in the maps in this scenario?
Note: I am using Satellite view in my maps

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure you can't. The docs say that Google Maps doesn't provide download content and store it for a "long time". It is just allowed to cache some location information to provide a better user experience.

Google says:

> (c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content. You must not use the
>   Service in a manner that gives you or any other person access to mass
>   downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, including but not limited to
>   numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, visible map
>   data, or places data (including business listings). For example, you
>   are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content
>   contained in the Maps API(s).

[Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=de)

But maybe you can provide a screen-shot functionality?